# webpack hmr + socketio "user connected" spam when initialize

Tags: reactjs, webpack, socket.io, webpack-hmr

I'm trying socketio with webpack dev server using hmr. I'm not sure if it's related to my problem.

This is the most simple example I use:

Server side:

```
this.io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Client side (inside a react component):

```
componentDidMount() {
    var socket = io();
}
```

The problem when I do that it's "a user connected" appears a lot on the server side like if io() function is constantly called. It's spamming io connection.

Any idea where does this come from ? related to hmr or webpack ?

Edit:
I've try to initialize socketIO own server
Server side:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000 , function() {
        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;
        console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    });
    var ioServer = http.listen(process.env.PORT || 9090 , function() {
        var host = ioServer.address().address;
        var port = ioServer.address().port;
        console.log('IO listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    });
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9090');
```

But it's the same result "a user connected" heavy spam. Hundreds of connection to io.

Comment: This is probably related to hrm. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584724/how-to-use-socket-io-together-with-webpack-hot-middleware

Comment: good hint but I already have this implementation it seems not working ..